# Issues when entering password finishing with '^' character

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, password, internationalization

I am using a password that has been generated by the organization where I work, and that specific password terminates with the `^` character. This password cannot be changed so I must keep it for the rest of my life.

The problem is that on a Mac, I can't enter this password properly (I am essentially talking about web pages with input forms when logging to my account.)

When writing into an HTML input box using a PC or on any Linux distribution, if I want to write the `^` character, I simply have to press the <kbd>^</kbd> key followed by a <kbd>space</kbd>. But using a mac, this process doesn't work, pressing <kbd>space</kbd> right after won't write the `^` character.

What I need to do every time I enter my password, is to write the `^` into a place I can see it, copy it, and paste it at the end of the input box. This way it works...

I have no idea where this can be fixed up...

Comment: What exacty happens if you press the <kbd>^</kbd> followed by <kbd>space</kbd>? It works fine for me as we speak:

http://up.frd.mn/FbUEmvpNGd.gif

Comment: It works everywhere, except into Password fields. In this particular case, the character isn't written...

Comment: By the way, how did you generated that .gif ?

Comment: What language keyboard? ^ is Shift/6 on an English keyboard.

Comment: I am using a Azerty (French) keyboard, using the apple mapping. So the '^' key is right next to the 'p' key.

Comment: My guess is that key is not mapping correctly on a Mac. On phone, can't test at the moment.

Comment: I think it has something to do specifically with web pages, and as I said, with html intputs with attribute type=password.

Comment: @MalteseFalcon You are totally right, I can confirm the same behaviour on password inputs. The first character that is recognized by the input is the "Space" key, even you i've hit "^" before.

Edit: I use the OS X' Quicktime application to record a screen video and then turn it into a gif using [gifify](https://github.com/jclem/gifify)

Comment: That's really annoying ... And I don't know if it could be fixed... I could write some JS code to deal with it...
Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: The keyboard's your problem, don't use a foreign keyboard with weird characters, and the problem will be solved! (/s)

Comment: A practical question: can you inform your organization that this password cannot be used because of the '^' character, and explain the convolutions you need to go through just to login?